# .img-responsive not found on Bootstrap website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am learning bootstrap by following some tutorials.  I was trying to learn more about `.img-responsive` from

`<img class="img-responsive" src="...some link...">`.

But I couldn't find `.img-responsive` on bootstrap doc.  This is as close to what I can find on bootstrap: [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/images/.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/images/)  However, I was able to find it on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp).  Is it because bootstrap 4.1 doesn't have `.img-responsive` or did I miss something?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.img-responsive` has been renamed to `.img-fluid`

In the docs for Bootstrap 4.0, you can find it here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/#responsive-images

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap v4.0 (or higher) images are made responsive with the `.img-fluid` class.